# Retrieving the favicon url of the websites from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I want to retrieve the favicon url of the website once it is loaded. How can I implement this for my firefox extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nsIFaviconService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIFaviconService), it caches favicons for known pages. Along these lines:

```
var faviconService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/favicon-service;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIFaviconService);
var favicon = faviconService.getFaviconImageForPage(gBrowser.currentURI);
alert(favicon.spec);
```

Please note that it works with [`nsIURI` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIURI), not with strings. You can use [nsIIOService.newURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIIOService#newURI%28%29) to get an `nsIURI` object from a string.

<sub>Yes, I realize that I am duplicating karthik's answer - but it has no explanation and only a bogus code example.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIFaviconService
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Places_favicon_service

Please read the page carefully. You can use the service defined below:

```
nsIServiceManager serviceManager = 
Mozilla.getInstance().getServiceManager(); 
nsIFaviconService service = 
(nsIFaviconService)serviceManager.getServiceByContractID("@mozilla.org/brows 
er/favicon-service;1", nsIFaviconService.NS_IFAVICONSERVICE_IID);
```